# How to get ordered product count in magento 2.4

Tags: product, checkout, orders, magento2.4, count

How to get ordered product count of product. I want to how many product is there in that order?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

    $orderItems = $_order->getAllItems();
    
    $productItemcount = 0;
    
    $productItemcount = count($orderItems);
```